# jQuery: Hide Ajax Loaded Div After Additional Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
jQuery('.delete-tag').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    var data_string = "ajax=1&tag-id=" + id + "";

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: file_path + "tags/edit/delete/",
        data: data_string,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(ajax_output) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The `.delete-tag` link is loaded via ajax in a modal window. I use `live()` to bind the click event for this link. Ajax runs ok, but I can't get the `hide()` to work on the ajax loaded link.

Suggestions? Everything works except the hiding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once inside the ajax success function, the `this` points to a different object. Store the origional reference in another variable:

```
var orig = jQuery(this);
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: file_path + "tags/edit/delete/",
        data: data_string,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(ajax_output) {
            orig.hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you know, I actually new that. It just didn't cross my mind because I thought it was another `live()` issue. Thanks!